# Read output of file or command inline in vim

Tags: vim

Lets say I have a text file open in Vim, that looks like so

```
this is an inline insertion
```

and I want to add the word "test" between "inline" and "insertion".

I could just write it in, but this is a metaphoric example, so I'm going to `:read !printf "test "` with the cursor at column 18. Here's what I get:

```
this is an inline insertion
test
```

Here's what I want to get:

```
this is an inline test insertion
```

Is there any way to create a vim function or is there an existing command I can use to get this behavior? I know I could do the read, then do `D` `k`, then place the cursor, then `P`, but I was hoping to find a way to do this in one step, placing the cursor ahead of time.

#### EDIT

Thanks to @melpomene's answer, I have this function in my `~/.vimrc` file now:

```
fu! InlineRead(command)
  let colnum = col('.')
  let line = getline('.')
  call setline('.', strpart(line, 0, colnum) . system(a:command) . strpart(line, colnum))
endfu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it manually by combining a few other functions:

```
:call setline('.', strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.')) . system('printf "test "') . strpart(getline('.'), col('.')))
```

Of course you can simplify this a bit by assigning the results of e.g. `col('.')` and `getline('.')` to variables, removing redundant computation:

```
let c = col('.')
let line = getline('.')
call setline('.', strpart(line, 0, c) . system('printf "test "') . strpart(line, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any setup (as in @melpomene's answer), you can directly insert external command output via [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R), the *expression register* ([`:help quote=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%3D)), and [`:help system()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) in insert mode:

```
<C-R>=system('printf "test "')<CR>
```

An alternative implementation is the following `` <C-R>` `` mapping for insert and command-line mode:

#### custom mapping

```
" i_CTRL-R_`        Insert the output of an external command.
" c_CTRL-R_`
function! s:QueryExternalCommand( newlineReplacement )
    call inputsave()
    let l:command = input('$ ', '', 'shellcmd')
    call inputrestore()
    return (empty(l:command) ?
    \   '' :
    \   substitute(substitute(l:command, '\n\+$', '', ''), '\n', a:newlineReplacement, 'g')
    \)
endfunction
inoremap <C-r>` <C-g>u<C-r>=<SID>QueryExternalCommand('\r')<CR>
cnoremap <C-r>` <C-r>=<SID>QueryExternalCommand('\\n')<CR>
```